# specify /boot folder during installation, since / drive is not accessible by BIOS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have a Dell desktop at work with a 3.5" spinning HDD with Windows installed on it, and a NVMe SSD that I installed in a PCIe x4 adapter, as the motherboard doesn't offer an NVMe slot. Problem is, the BIOS doesn't recognize the NVMe drive, and it's only after the kernel is loaded that it is. This becomes problematic when installing Ubuntu using the standard installation process, as it obviously has no way of knowing that the drive I'm installing it to (the NVMe) is not recognized by the BIOS. So it ends up installing the /boot folder to that NVMe, which causes Grub to fallback to the rescue prompt when booting up the system.

One solution would be to simply create a boot partition on the 3.5" drive that's recognized by the BIOS, with the root filesystem on the NVMe. But in the interest of tidiness, I'd like to have it create the /boot folder in the ESP partition which already contains the Windows Boot Manager. **How can I install the bootloader files to a /boot directory contained on that EFI partition, while installing the root filesystem to the NVMe SSD? I have tried boot-rescue and manually re-installing grub, but that doesn't work as it simply installs grub to the EFI partition with the /boot files still located on the NVMe, as it again is unaware that this won't work since the NVMe isn't recognizable by the BIOS.**

Comment: Do not confuse the ESP - efi system partition with a /boot partition. You just need to add a ext4 partition as /boot on HDD and installer will put kernel & rest of grub into that partition. Initial UEFI grub boot files are still in ESP. There is something new where you can  put kernels into ESP, but that then does not use grub and is not a standard configuration. If an advanced user you can look up gummiboot which is now part of systemD and how to configure that. see also:NVME Samsung 970 Evo Plus drive using a PCIe card
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2415658

Comment: right. I'm not confusing the two. Just was hoping to place the /boot kernel files within the EFI partition as well, but may just go with obvious solution I mentioned of simply creating a /boot partition on the bootable, BIOS-recognized HDD and placing the root filesystem on the NVMe which the BIOS does not recognize

Comment: I went ahead and did that and it works quite well. I'm satisfied with that as a workable solution.

Comment: You can now post what you did as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Went ahead with solution I mentioned of simply creating a /boot partition on the bootable, BIOS-recognized HDD and placing the root filesystem on the NVMe which the BIOS does not recognize. Grub was properly installed to the /EFI partition (shared with the Windows Boot Manger), the kernel boot files to the /boot partition, and the root file system to the NVMe. Works as expected and well enough for my needs.